# Парсинг ISO образа на Python

Tags: python, iso-образ

Как прочитать iso-образ из программы (простите за опечатку) на python?

Answer (score 1):

если мне память не изменяет и не спит с другим *.ISO это самый обычный zip архиф с мета данными в виде файлика внутри, а значит python модули zlib и zipfile вам помогут решить свою задачу..

Comment: Спасибо, попробую